# Open JPA Saving OneToMany , foreign key not set

Tags: java, openjpa

I've two tables: TaStock and TaStockPrice. Field tastockid in table TaStockPrice is the foreign key to table TaStock.

```
@Entity
public class TaStock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taStock", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TaStockPrice> tastockpriceList;

    public void addTaStockPrice(TaStockPrice taStockPrice) {
       if (taStockPrice == null) {
           return;
       }
       taStockPrice.setTaStock(this);
       if (tastockpriceList == null) {
           tastockpriceList = new ArrayList<TaStockPrice>();
           tastockpriceList.add(taStockPrice);
       } else if (!tastockpriceList.contains(taStockPrice)) {
           tastockpriceList.add(taStockPrice);
       }
    }
    ....
}



@Entity
public class TaStockPrice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id
    @Column
    private Integer tastockid;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tastockid", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private TaStock taStock;
    ...
}
```

**persisting taStock with Children**

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void createTaStock() throws Exception {
    TaStock taStock = new TaStock();
             ...

    TaStockPrice taStockPrice = new TaStockPrice();
             ...

    taStock.addTaStockPrice(taStockPrice);
    taStockService.persist(taStock);
}
```

I read that when persisting a parent class, hibernate automatically persist the children of that class. But instead, the following exception occurs:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: null value in column "tastockid" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Why do you need the `tastockid` column definition? JPA does not work like this, you can refer to foreign key by `taStockPrice.getTaStock().getId()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I removed  `private Integer tastockid"` from `TaStockPrice`, and modified
`@JoinColumn(name = "tastockid", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)` to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that also solved it for me. Do you have an explanation about how setting insertable to true solves the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @JoinColumn is insertable = true by default

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the collection as being not insertable nor updateable. This way hibernate will never persist it.

You could set how hibernate should treat this relation using the cascade-setting in your annotation. For more information, here is a thorough blog-post on the subject: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/.

Comment: Hi,  I looked ath the example on www.mkyong.com. In order to be synchrone with the example I just have to add the statement  taStockPrice.setTaStock(taStock); . The collection is insertable/updatable because I have annotated the collection with : cascade = CascadeType.ALL.  I still have the same exception message.

Comment: With my current setup, hibernate doesn't seem to set field tastockid.  How Can I make sure that hibernate recognised tastockid as the foreign key, and sets this field when saving TaStock ?

Comment: The DB table tastockprice , the following field is defined "tastockid integer NOT NULL" , and the following constraint: CONSTRAINT tastockprice_tastockid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (tastockid)
      REFERENCES tastock (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: I had to set `insertable = false, updatable = false` on my child column definition to get the cascading insert to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use below annotation on `tastockpriceList`.

`@OneToMany`
  `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)`
  `@JoinColumn(name="tastock")`

That should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I had the `@OneToOne` contallation and had the same problem. I have removed `nullable = false, updatable = false` and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable save ability on a `@OneToMany` relation e.g.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="myTable", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<item> items;
```

Then you have to tell to your `@ManyToOne` relation is allowed to update myTable like this updatable = true

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fk_myTable", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
```